# Determine what satellites to display on screen in Augmented reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality app, where i want to display the satellites based on the direction in which the device pointing at.

Consider i get the azimuth and elevation from the orientation sensor of the device. I also get the azimuth and elevation from the GpsSatellite class. With these values how will i place the satellite on the camera view. How can i convert these values to screen coordinates?

BR

Suppi

Comment: seriously, why am i getting downvoted??

Comment: That is a very good question, this is a perfectly legitimate question to ask. Have an upvote.

Comment: I've never actually delved into the azimuth and elevation properties for the satellites - are they with respect to true north and the equator?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the code of [mixare](https://github.com/mixare/mixare). Please consider that it's an open source project released under the GPLv3 license, this means that if you build on top of it you have to publish your work under the same license.

In the case you don't want to code the augmented reality app by yourself, you can write a launcher for mixare. All the documentation is available on the project [page](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/DisplayYourOwnData). The data format is pretty straight-forward.

HTH,
DAniele

Comment: thanks Daniele, this is very helpful. But is there some kind of documentation to understand what each class does?

Comment: I'm sorry there isn't anything organic yet. But you can take a look at this two commits to get a lot of info: https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/mixare/commit/23f6108f4cfb7efcf800f478ecb147e2ddd19906 https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/mixare/commit/49f3e091cddb5d1547f961f22a733b4ac4345430 HTH